# Can we name the 6 degrees of freedom of a 2d affine transform in an intuitive manner?

Tags: transformation, affine-geometry

A 2d affine transformation is characterized by the following formula:
$$
   x' = a x + b y + c,  \\
   y' = d x + e y + f.
$$

Hence it has 6 degrees of freedom.  I can name the following 5 special types:

- translate parallel to the $x$-axis
- translate parallel to the $y$-axis
- rotate inside $xy$-plane about the origin $O$
- scale in the direction of $x$-axis
- scale in the direction of $y$-axis

The above types are basic, intuitive (has clear geometric meaning) and 'independent'. What is the other basic and independent type? I can think of 2 other basic types:

- shear parallel to the $x$-axis
- shear parallel to the $y$-axis

The problem is we need one more, not two more! Can we find ONE extra intuitive type that are independent of the above 5 types?

NOTE: Edited after reading EricTowers' answer.

A x-translate and a 90 degrees rotation will generate a y-translate.
A x-scale and a 90 degrees rotation will generate a y-scale.
A x-shear and a 90 degrees rotation will generate a y-shear.

It is common to think of the two translates, two scaling and 1 rotation in describing affines. Each of the above operation requires 1 continuous parameter.
So if we combine them in 6 different orders (repetition of same type allowed); we will obtain all possible affines.

I don't want to include another two shears, partly because I want one only and don't want to be forced to single out the x-shear or y-shear. A total of 7 affines to describe affines when we should only need 6 ways to describe. I am curious if it is possible to do it with exactly 6 different types.

On the other hand, we can go minimum and just do the following 3 and obtain all affines (repetition of same type allowed):
x-translation, x-scale and rotation

Comment: You’ve left out reflections, so there are even *more* “basic” types.

Comment: What makes oyu think the two shears are independent?  A $\pi/2$ rotation of one shear is a shear of the other type.

Comment: Reflection is different from others in the way I am looking for answer, it does not take a continuous range of parameters: it is binary. It does not feel like it span a whole degree of freedom.

Comment: @EricTowers Thanks for the response. I edited my question to make my question more clear.

Answer (score 2):

The two shears and rotation are dependent. The proper setting for this is the infinitesimal versions, i.e. the generators of these transforms. For rotation it is $\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
-1 &  0
\end{bmatrix}$ while for the shears the generators are $\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
0 &  0
\end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
1 &  0
\end{bmatrix}$. These are the matrices representing the generators inside the lie algebra of the linear group, i.e. in $gl(2)$, the 2 by 2 matrices.  The full group of affine transformations has a 2d version of the lie algebra of [twists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screw_theory#Twists_as_elements_of_a_Lie_algebra) as the set of infinitesimal generators. The $gl(2)$ sits inside it as the matrix part. The two coordinate scalings and the 2 translations along the axes are generated by 4 other independent twists (the translations give the vector part, and the scalings the two other independent vectors in the matrix part).